# When will the kernel 5.10.0-1058-oem be released and available in the repositories?

Tags: 20.04, kernel

When is approximate date the kernel 5.10.0-1058-oem will be available? Currently I use kernel 5.10.0-1057-oem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably very soon.

It is already in *focal-proposed* - see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-5.10/5.10.0-1058.62 and related https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1955246 .

You have to wait for it to be released in *focal-updates* after all comprehensive testing done.